# Как сделать ссылку таблицы на саму себя - еntity framework, model first?

Tags: entity-framework

Создаю модель как на рисунке: список слов, у которых есть ссылка на другие слова. Но при заполнении таблиц данными, когда слова ссылаются друг на друга, выскакивает ошибка циклической ссылки. 
Правильно ли я составил схему, как избежать ошибки? 
[image: Схема]

Comment: Нужно добавить еще одно поле, например, WordParentId, которое и будет указывать на своего родителя. Если это и есть родитель то оно будет пустое. Кроме того нужно будет создать foreign key на это поле и связать его с WordId.

Comment: Непонятно, как в моделе это настроить, там нет доступа к полям для настройки отдельных foreign key.

Comment: Правой кнопкой по таблице Word выбираем Add scalar property для добавление поля, а потом Add navigation property для добавления ключа.

Comment: @null а существующее свойство навигации оставить? Не будет это то же самое?

Comment: Можно оставить, но соответственно отредактировать или удалить и создать новое, правильное.